# yielding data members in binary search tree

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I am trying to implement an iterator to my binary search tree. To achieve this, I am attempting to do an in-order traversal through the tree and yield each individual data member. This will allow me to iterate through each item of the tree.

My function:

```
def __iter__(self):
    """
    in-order traversal of a binary search tree
    """
    if self.root is not None:
        self.check(self.root)

def check(self, cur_node):
    if cur_node is not None:
        self.check(cur_node.left)
        yield cur_node.data #if I were to print this data member, it would be fine
        self.check(cur_node.right)
```

When testing this function with an iteration such as

```
for i in tree:
```

I am receiving this error:

```
TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'NoneType'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To implement a recursive generator you cannot just "call" yourself, you need to extract elements and yield them.

Python has a special syntax for this:

```
 yield from expr
```

where `expr` is iterable, and it can be seen as a shorthand for

```
 for x in expr:
     yield x
```

Using this you can implement in-order traversal of a tree with something like:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, left, right):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def __iter__(self):
        if self.left:
            yield from self.left
        yield self.data
        if self.right:
            yield from self.right
```

Answer (score 2):

The clue is

> iter() returned ....

So you need to return an iterator. Your class is an iterator, so return self

```
def __iter__(self):
    """
    in-order traversal of a binary search tree
    """
    if self.root is not None:
        self.check(self.root)
    return self
```

You should probably implement `__next__` as well to actually yield the value.

So the solution might look like

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(...): ...

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.left is not None:
            yield from self.left
        yield self.data
        if self.right is not None:    
            yield from self.right
```

You use `yield from` here to delegate to the child nodes. See https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380-syntax-for-delegating-to-a-subgenerator

You do in fact need three yield statements, because you need to traverse both the left and right children, as well as producing the value of the current node.

Comment: Changing the internal state for an enumeration operation is a bad idea... what if multiple users want to iterate the same tree at the same time?

Comment: I am going through an infinite loop? I have made a slight adjustment to your code by editing cur_node.left to self.cur_node.left. Are you sure we need 3 yield statements?

Comment: I've updated this to address the mulitthreading issue and using the class attributes.

Answer (score 2):

You generally want your iterator as a separate entity from your data structure, so you can have multiple iterators over your data, and so you can iterate over your data multiple times.  Below, I show how you can implement a simple DFS algorithm for a basic BST class.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
    def __iter__(self):
        return BSTIterator(self)

class BSTIterator:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.stack = []
        curr = root
        while curr:
            self.stack.append(curr)
            curr = curr.left
    def __next__(self):
        if not self.stack:
            raise StopIteration()
        node = self.stack.pop()
        val = node.val
        node = node.right
        while node:
            self.stack.append(node)
            node = node.left
        return val
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

root = Node(5, Node(3, Node(1), Node(4)), Node(10, (Node(6, None, Node(7)))))
list(root)
# [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10]
```